# How to change the ABSPATH in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been trying to create a dummy duplicate of a custom-built WP/WooCommerce Site on the same server.

I've successfully moved the files to a subdomain and created a temp DB copy and updated the wp_config file, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to set the ABSPATH value to reflect the subdomain instead of the main (non-test) domain. So now when you log in to the dummy WP site, it logs into the WP dashboard of the MAIN site.

**So my question is how do I change the ABSPATH value for the dummy site and will that also update the dummy URLs to point to the site URLs?

The main site URL is ldtuttle.com and the dummy site is dev.tuttle.com.

Thanks in advance for your time, 
Lisa

Comment: You don't need to change the `ABSPATH`. You need to replace the URLs of the main site `http://mainsite.com` with dummy new subdomain `http://subdomain.dummy.com`. Or you can hardcode the urls in `wp-config.php` file by adding `define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://subdomain.dummy.com/wordpress' ); define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://subdomain.dummy.com/wordpress' );` for now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two values in the 'wp_options' database table you need to change, 'siteurl' and 'home'.

This will tell Wordpress where to redirect a user for the login screen, and is normally filled out automatically when Wordpress initially creates the database on a domain.

Comment: @RahilWazir in my experience it does... otherwise Wordpress will redirect to the /wp-admin site of the old domain for every page, like the OP is describing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update more than Just the  'wp_options'

Also create a separate database for the- "dummy duplicate" -  copy the original database there and then, update these database tables:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = REPLACE(option_value, 'ORIGINAL_URL', 'NEW_URL');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, 'ORIGINAL_URL', 'NEW_URL');
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE(guid, 'ORIGINAL_URL', 'NEW_URL');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'ORIGINAL_URL', 'NEW_URL');
```

---

Some good articles:

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-staging-environment-for-a-wordpress-site/

### And:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

See Header: Moving Directories On Your Existing Server

Comment: "How to break your WordPress install in 4 easy queries." This doesn't account for serialised data which will break if your new domain isn't exactly the same length as your old one. The only reliable method that works properly in current versions of PHP is [wp-cli search and replace](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/).

Comment: Nice condescending and patronizing rude response #Walf. Don't need wordpress to do a search and replace for us... something I think we can handle

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add one thing related to @kreeverp's comment: you should be careful about replacing the GUID value, as [the WordPress Codex explains](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL). If you are moving FROM local development TO deployment, then it is safe to change them to the deployment URL. But if you are moving from one URL to another, both of which are deployed (e.g., changing from site.com to site.org) then you do NOT want to replace the GUID value.

(I would have left this as a comment to @kreeverp, but I can't do that yet!)